# google-code-prettify removes text in angle bracket

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, google-code-prettify

I am using google-code-prettify to syntax-highlight CPP code. I used it as follows.

```html
<script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js?lang=cpp"></script>
<pre class="prettyprint"><code>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "Hellow world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
</code>
</pre>
```

### In the result I get, the "iostream" part is gone. But the rest of the code is syntax-highlighted perfectly :)

```html
#include 

using namespace std;

int main(){

    cout << "Hellow world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

I tried other codes in between "<" and ">". They were removed too. Why is this so? How do I get the whole code?

Thanks for your help
BR
//Asmelash Tse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because it gets interpreted as a HTML tag. If you want them not to be replace

```
< with &lt;
> with &gt;
```